# Stop plotly representing time series as seconds for datetime and timestamp data

Tags: pandas, plotly

I'm trying out Plotly for some front-end visuals I want to display using Dash. It seems useful enough, but I'm getting snagged on a datetime issue. Specifically, when I pass a pandas dataframe containing timestamp or datetime information, the presence of seconds means that the time axis displays the time in seconds using scientific notation. For instance, see the chart on the link below (plotly generates online images):
[image]
My code is pretty straightforward; see below:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

info = pd.read_pickle('filepath.pkl')

trace = go.Scatter(x = info['publication_time'], y = info['jsd'], mode = 'lines', name = 'jsd')

data = [trace]

py.plot(data, filename = 'time-series-simple', auto_open=True)
```

Note that I can 'solve' this problem by converting my 'publication_time' values using `date()`, as below. 
[image]
But when I do this, I lose all the time info bar the calendar date, which is problematic in the context of my data.

Any help appreciated!

Edit: Sample data for illustration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [Timestamp('2013-06-17 22:00:44'),
 Timestamp('2013-08-06 21:31:46'),
 Timestamp('2013-08-14 00:03:40'),
 Timestamp('2014-01-23 19:16:02'),
 Timestamp('2014-02-03 22:07:19'),
 Timestamp('2014-04-08 16:34:29'),
 Timestamp('2014-04-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-07-24 10:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-24 13:10:41')], 'Value':[0.9259890294026274,
 0.8475729796693869,
 0.811830101974202,
 0.7727937137247451,
 0.6815034448835853,
 0.41908808936508635,
 0.6908772808127566,
 0.9425539823548483,
 0.7876344379636819]})
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a sample of your data. In other words a reproducible example? See [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, should have done that. Have now added some sample data that should allow the problem to be reproduced. Thanks!

Comment: What format are you expecting at the x-axis? `YYYY-MM-DD` or do you need `HH-MM-SS` as well. Do you want the ticks to match your dates?

Comment: I'd like YYYY-MM-DD-HH-SS. All of this doesn't need to display at all scales, but because plotly allows for plots to be magnified to arbitrary degree, the HH-SS resolution needs to be available. Right now, when I do a timestamp to datetime conversion using `date()`, the best I can get is MM-DD.